# What OTK abbreviation stands for?

Tags: drums

I've heard about it when someone was talking about drum mic positions, but I'm not sure. Is it something like overhead mic position?

Comment: My guess would be "Over the Kit", but I've never directly heard that phrase before.

Comment: I've never heard the term either, in 40 years of engineering [on & off]. Maybe I just live a sheltered life ;)

Comment: I saw it in this video and it sound like overhead. Look how channel is named. https://youtu.be/jrfF1XMdpc8

Comment: @Tetsujin I think it’s partly a recent fad and partly a slight change to the concept of a “crotch mic”, which I’ve heard of before.

Answer (score 2):

OTK? On the kick. Not in front or inside, but actually 'on the kick'. Mounted on the rim of the bass drum.

Comment: Is there any technical or practical reason to mic the kick this way?

Comment: Technical: in front picks up the resonant head. Inside picks up the 'thud'. OTK with a clamp can be moved around to pick up what sounds best, without resorting to a mic stand as the first example needs.

Comment: I think that this otk setting will pick a lot of sound from other elements of kit like snare and cymbals. Is this right? I've seen a video in which OTK channel in daw sounded like it was overhead. That's the video: https://youtu.be/jrfF1XMdpc8

Comment: Any source for this?

Comment: @Ronx Yeah looks like it’s a different take on the idea of a crotch mic. Sorta like LCR (left, center, right) miking for drums.

Comment: Everything I’ve seen on this suggests this answer is incorrect. There are so many bad things about rim mounted drum mics it’s hard to know where to start.

Comment: That's a plausible answer, @Tim, but do you have any backup for it?

Comment: @LaurencePayne - 'recording lounge' drum mixing 303 was one place. OTK - Rode NT2 right in front of the rim of the kick. Which may or may not actually be *mounted* on the rim, but would certainly be in line with the rim/circumference of the head. Some rim mounts transfer sound not required, so it could easily be on a small stand. Wasn't easy to find info on 'otk'.

Answer (score 2):

At least one person in a podcast defines it as “over the kick”. This looks like an automatic transcription that has no punctuation and I have quoted it exactly (emphasis mine):

> anyway okay so here's a mic that I was talking about earlier the **otk over the kick Mike** so this Mike is literally over the kick drum like maybe an inch or two over the kick drum either facing down at the kick drum facing the snare sometimes facing the floor tom sometimes it's more at the rim of the kick drum have to experiment the place in a little bit I tend to like somewhere around the middle of the kick drum facing the snare kind of equidistant between like floor tom rack Tom and snare sort of where those sort of have a middle point somewhere around the center of the kick drum underneath the ride cymbal somewhere in there and this is what that might sounds like this is a really interesting Mike

Source: https://www.listennotes.com/podcasts/recording-lounge/episode-111-drums-in-a-small-21KrG0ePJaI/

If you look at the table and picture closely on this site:

https://www.recordingloungepodcast.com/blog/episode-93-drum-mixing-303-additional-info

you’ll see that there is a mic that looks like the OTK mic boomed in from the hi hat side over the batter side rim of the kick.

This video goes with that site and the OTK mic is pointed out at around 6:10:

I suspect this is partly a batter side kick mic for picking up articulation and/or kind of a crotch mic that gets a nice central image of the kit.

Comment: I guess it may be the good idea if you have only 2 mics to put one as overhead and one as OTK aaato gather the entire spectrum of sounds, well entire for what's possible with 2 mics of course hehe.